# Trying to identify varistor values off an ancient power supply

Tags: components, charger, varistor

[image: Unidentified varistor]

Was tricky to get a photo with the markings visible, but as best I can tell the markings read...

```
H L1
1502
```

...The scoring down the middle is from where I haphazardly removed the heat-shrink which was around the component

I have two which have blown and am trying to source replacements.
[Would this be a suitable drop-in replacement?](http://www.galco.com/scripts/cgiip.exe/wa/wcat/catalog.htm?searchbox=V150LA2P) ([closeup](http://www.galco.com/images/lf/large/v150la2p_p.jpg))

Thanks.

---

For reference, the components are off an old Motorola power supply (board is marked 1991 manufactured by a company named Astec) which is used for charging GP300 handheld radios. Charger output spec is 14V @ 10A (charges up to 6x radios at once).

Comment: What is the capacitor load on the other side of it?

Comment: Jeez.  You make me feel old.  I used to program GP300 radios at work.  Now you refer to them as ancient.